# Modal Assync Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, modal

Tó tentando fazer uma modal reusável vuejs passando um objeto para edição ou cadastro mas estou travado na forma como passar o objeto de forma assíncrona, já que o objeto que quero passar vai ser mudado quando o usuário clicar no botão editar por exemplo.

Foi feito o component que o template está abaixo:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    propE: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  mounted() {},
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
  }
};
</script>
```

Por outro lado foi adicionado o component com o nome "modalDinamic"
Dado o objeto na forma de :

```
Prop:{
   jose:'Miguel'
}
```

A declaração ficou:

```
<modal-dinamic :propE="Prop"></modal-dinamic>
```

Para ser mais claro, no elemento pai terá um metodo que dirá que

```
this.Prop={
    jose:'joaquin'
}
```

e desta forma dá um $('#myModal').show();
Espero ter sido claro agora.

Comment: Podes mostrar o que já tens? ou criar um exemplo do código?

Comment: Adicionei mais dados como vc pediu, criei um codigo exemplo

Comment: As props são passadas por referência. Tens a certeza que o problema que descreves existe mesmo? Talvez seja eu que não percebi bem. Esse `Prop` é um objeto? então no modal podes aceder via `this.propE`.

Comment: O problema é que esta Prop vai ser atualizada, e o dado é passado como se fosse o primeiro valor que o objeto assume, e a necessidade é que seja dinamica.

Comment: Mas como é um objeto as mudanças que fizeres num sitio são acessíveis noutro lado. Podes montar um exemplo que funcione com o problema? tenho gosto em ajudar

Comment: Esse Modal é jQuery?

Comment: Bootstrap, Usei ele por facilitar o trabalho

Comment: E o exemplo acima o problema ocorre.

Comment: No site do Vuejs tem o exemplo de modal, segue link: https://br.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html. Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente eu recomendaria instanciar o objeto de CRUD somente quando necessário. Assim:

```html
<modal-dinamic :propE="Prop" v-if="exibirModal"></modal-dinamic>
```

Outra opção seria controlar a abertura de uma modal com um event. Pesquise por this.$emit

Você poderia inclusive passar o objeto por parametro nesse momento

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde amigo! Já passei pelo mesmo dilema, e pesquisei muito, acabei concluindo que a melhor solução pro meu caso era chamar um método do componente filho dentro do componente pai através de $refs, vou te mostrar meu exemplo de código:

Componente pai "clientes":

```
this.$refs.clienteDialog.show(cliente);
```

Componente filho "clienteDialog":

```
show(cliente) {
            this.dialog = true;
            this.cliente = { ...cliente };
}
```